# Extension that Adds group_price and base_group_price to Index Tables

Tags: indexing, price-rules

I'm working with a client to help track down the root cause of a `Insert value list does not match column list:` error.

It's a system that claims to be Magento 1.6.1.  Somewhere in the system's life it's price index tables

```
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp
```

picked up the columns `group_price` and `base_group_price`.  From what I've been able to determine, these are not part of a standard Magento 1.6.1 system, which confuses the price indexers `insertFromSelect` call, leading to the error.

I realize you can't debug my specific system, but I'm wondering if anyone's run across an extension that adds these fields to the tables.  I'm planning an audit of the system, but if there's known science in the community that'd save me countless hours code glopping, I'd apprecaite.

Answer (score 1):

Those match a 1.7.0.2 database structure - perhaps they had a botched upgrade sometime in the past?

Source: http://www.magereverse.com/

Comment: That's one of my working theories as well, although the core_resource table matches a 1.6.1 installation.  Botches is the operative work here. What was the extension you thought this might be?

Comment: Thought it might have something to do with the Innoexts Warehouse or Store View Prices extensions - know they do some heavy database modifications and have caused numerous headaches for people in the past

Comment: Got it — even if it's not the answer for my specific question, it's good to have that information here for people who come by later.

Comment: You could run the db repair tool. If they had a botched upgrade it would be apparent from the output.